# Square Brackets in Python Regular Expressions (re.sub)

Tags: python, regex

## The Issue

I'm migrating wiki pages from the FlexWiki engine to the FOSwiki engine using Python regular expressions to handle the differences between the two engines' markup languages.

The [FlexWiki markup](http://wiki.squirrel-lang.org/default.aspx/SquirrelWiki/FormattingRules.html) and the [FOSwiki markup](http://foswiki.org/System/TextFormattingRules), for reference.

Most of the conversion works very well, *except* when I try to convert the renamed links.
Both wikis support renamed links in their markup.

For example, Flexwiki uses:

```
"Link To Wikipedia":[http://www.wikipedia.org/]
```

FOSwiki uses:

```
[[http://www.wikipedia.org/][Link To Wikipedia]]
```

Both of which produce a rewritten hyperlink.

I'm using the regular expression

```
renameLink = re.compile ("\"(?P<linkText>[^\"]+)\":\[(?P<linkTarget>[^\[\]]+)\]")
```

to parse out the link elements from the FlexWiki markup, which after running through something like

```
"Link Text":[LinkTarget]
```

is reliably producing groups

```
<linkText> = Link Text
<linkTarget = LinkTarget
```

My issue occurs when I try to use re.sub to insert the parsed content into the FOSwiki markup.

My experience with regular expressions isn't anything to write home about, but I'm under the impression that, given the groups

```
<linkText> = Link text
<linkTarget = LinkTarget
```

a line like

```
line = renameLink.sub ( "[[\g<linkTarget>][\g<linkText>]]" , line )
```

should produce

```
[[LinkTarget][Link Text]]
```

However, in the output to the text files I'm getting

```
[[LinkTarget [[Link Text]]
```

which breaks the renamed links.

After a little bit of fiddling I managed a workaround, where

```
line = renameLink.sub ( "[[\g<linkTarget>][ [\g<linkText>]]" , line )
```

produces

```
[[LinkTarget][ [[Link Text]]
```

which, when displayed in FOSwiki looks like

```
[[Link Text
```

Which WORKS, but isn't very pretty.

There are probably thousands of instances of these renamed links in the pages I'm trying to convert, so fixing it by hand isn't any good.
For the record I've run the script under Python 2.5.4 and Python 2.7.3, and gotten the same results.

Am I missing something really obvious with the syntax? Or is there an easy workaround?

## Solution

There wasn't anything wrong with the original expression.

I started running through the other regex's in my script and commented out lines I thought might be overlapping with the renamed-link expression. That appears to have done the trick, and as a semi-permanent fix I've separated the link-focused expressions and the other expressions into separate scripts, which I run one after another.

I guess them moral here is to double-check that you don't have overlapping expressions.

### Attempted Solutions (Just see Solution above)

String addition

```
line = renameLink.sub ( "[[\g<linkTarget>]" + "[\g<linkText>]]" , line )
```

produces

```
[[linkTarget [[Link Text]]
```

It doesn't matter how you slice the concatenation, the result is the same.

Escaping the square brackets, e.g.

```
line = renameLink.sub ( "\[\[\g<linkTarget>\]\[\g<linkName>\]\]" , line )
```

produces

```
\[ [[LinkTarget\]] [Link Text\]\]
```

Comment: try to escape `[` and `]` by backslash, so use `\[` and `\]`

Comment: I just tried the code in the question and it worked without any problems. Is there some slight difference between the code here and what you're actually using, including things like double quotes versus single quotes, backslashes, etc.

Comment: Another idea is that something else later in your conversion is making the change.

Comment: @user1215106 I tried backslashes and I've added the results to the question.

Comment: @Geoff Reedy I'm only using double-quotes, and the code in the question is identical to what I'm using locally. I'm going to try to strip the conversion down to just the regular expressions processing the links and see if there isn't another expression reprocessing the lines in question.

Comment: Actually, as most commenters before stated, you regex is working well. Also, you can get some problems when using `\` inside a string. This is not going to give you issues in the case you use `\g`, because this sequence has no special meaning, but it would give problems if you have used, e.g., `\t` or `\n`, as you can imagine. You would be better using [raw strings](http://pages.citebite.com/c2n5c1u5hwls).

Comment: Update: I stripped the script of everything but the lines processing the links and my output was fixed, one of the other conversions is picking up the links and reprocessing them. I'll update when I have it working completely.

Comment: Oooh boy, you should read all answers and pick the one that is the most optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a line like
>
> ```
> line = renameLink.sub ( "[[\g<linkTarget>][\g<linkText>]]" , line )
> ```
>
> should produce
>
> ```
> [[LinkTarget][Link Text]]
> ```

And it does. Example:

```
line = r""""Link Text":[LinkTarget]"""
renameLink = re.compile("\"(?P<linkText>[^\"]+)\":\[(?P<linkTarget>[^\[\]]+)\]")
print(renameLink.sub ("[[\g<linkTarget>][\g<linkText>]]", line))
```

Output:

```
[[LinkTarget][Link Text]]
```

You probably have issues elsewhere than your expression.

Comment: I did not and I am waiting for the comment as to why it was down voted

Comment: you can cleanup the comment now

Comment: @user1215106, don't edit out the quote, quoting OP was intentional.

Comment: @Qtax Yep, from what I can tell the issue is in another conversion within the same script, I'll update this when I've got it working.

Answer (score 3):

### Flexwiki-to-FOSwiki

***Code:***

```
import re
text = '"Link To Wikipedia":[http://www.wikipedia.org/]'
print re.sub(r'"([^"]+)":\[([^\]]+)\]', r'[[\2][\1]]', text)
```

***Output:***

```
[[http://www.wikipedia.org/][Link To Wikipedia]]
```

*See and test the code [here](http://ideone.com/06JwB).*

Comment: +1 This is quite an elegant answer and does the substitution in one go

Answer (score 0):

I tried exactly as you said. I am using python 2.7.1 version.

Here is the result

```
>>> text = '"Link To Wikipedia":[http://www.wikipedia.org/]'
>>> renameLink = re.compile ("\"(?P<linkText>[^\"]+)\":\[(?P<linkTarget>[^\[\]]+)\]")
>>> s = renameLink.match(text)
>>> lnkname, lnk = s.groups()
>>> substr = "[[%s][%s]]" % (lnk, lnkname)
>>> renameLink.sub(substr, text)
'[[http://www.wikipedia.org/][Link To Wikipedia]]'
```

It works out all fine.